# get list of all view names in couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-nano

Is it possible to get a list of all the views of a database in couchdb using [dscape/nano][1]? The closest I can get with just curl request is this:

```
http://URL/DBNAME/_all_docs?key=_design/views&include_docs=true.
```

The above returns all the views including the javascript functions. But I would like to extract only the view names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the only possible way of doing this is by extracting view names from the result of the query you've included in your question. Futon is doing it this way when populating drop-down list of views, so I think it is safe to assume this is the only solution.

You may also want to change your query to the following to include all design documents, instead of just the one named `views`:

```
GET /dbname/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"&include_docs=true
```

Comment: thanks Arthur. I am just trying with the equivalent query in nano and it is possible. I will post the code in a moment. I already implemented the change you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

In newer CouchDB versions, you can use "_design_docs" to only list the views:

```
GET /dbname/_design_docs
```

This will get you the wanted list much faster than if you'd have to go through all the docs (_all_docs).

See [1.3.3. /{db}/_design_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-design-docs) of the official documentation.

Note: The documentation as of today states this is new in CouchDB version 2.2, but I successfully tested it on 2.1.